# How do I answer the phone in Lollipop Chainsaw?

Tags: lollipop-chainsaw

The first time that the phone icon appeared, Juliet answered it automatically, but since then I have no idea how to take the call. I've tried every button and combination of buttons I can think of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You actually don't need to (and can't) answer her phone. You will have to open up the menu by hitting the Start button, then going to Juliet's Stash. Tab to the Phone icon and then listen to the message.